# TSQLT Test Run Timeout

Tags: sql-server, unit-testing, tsqlt

I recently started using TSQLT through Redgate's SQL Test to create and run unit tests. I have run into a problem though. Unit tests that take more than a couple minutes to execute will time out, which halts the execution of all other unit tests.

How can I extend the length of the timeout  for tSQLt?

My "unit testing" is probably not actually unit testing, but I am not familiar with another testing methodology that fits better.

I am working on a project to improve the speed of the nightly refresh of our data warehouse. Currently, this process takes five hours. Through rearranging the tasks to run in parallel where possible, I have cut that time down to two hours. My problem is that unless I can find a way to prove that the new process has the exact same end result as the old process, QA will spend the next year checking every value in every column in every row in every table. Either that or the project will be scrapped as being "too hard".

So the testing that I have come up with is this:
I have a database where I run a script to copy over the resulting tables after they are processed in our testing environment using the new method that I created. Then, back in the testing environment, I run the old process to update the tables. Then, I run one unit test per table to prove that the contents of the archived tables processed using the new method is exactly identical to the contents of the tables re-processed using the old method.

Unfortunately due to the size of some of these tables (millions of rows) some of the unit tests are timing out. The following is the error that I am recieving:

> Test Procedure: [HR360_unitTest1].[HR360_DW_Job6].[test
>   fact_group_clients Identical Contents] on emr\preprod
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Timeout expired.  The
>   timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the
>   server is not responding. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception
>   (0x80004005): The wait operation timed out    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception,
>   Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior,
>   SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
>   BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds,
>   RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean
>   async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader
>   ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String
>   method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task,
>   Boolean asyncWrite)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1
>   completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout,
>   Boolean asyncWrite)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()    at
>   RedGate.SQLTest.tSQLt.FrameworkWrapper.#kz(SqlCommand #LGj)    at
>   RedGate.SQLTest.tSQLt.FrameworkWrapper.#7qHc(String #2xAd,
>   SqlParameter[] #LvPb)    at
>   RedGate.SQLTest.tSQLt.FrameworkWrapper.#qd4b(String #LGxc)    at
>   RedGate.SQLTest.tSQLt.TestRunner.Execute(SqlConnection connection)
>   ClientConnectionId:519569ed-03ce-4510-b226-9ff18e0f1d8d Error
>   Number:-2,State:0,Class:11

If there is no way to increase the timeout for tSQLt, then I will either have to find another way to automatically test that the contents of these tables is identical (in a way that is repeatable at-will) or abandon the project.

Comment: Have you tried changing the timeout property in the connection string?
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectiontimeout(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Unfortunately the call to the connection string is made by the tSQLt framework. I posted this question because I haven't been able to find a way to tell tSQLt to make these calls with a different timeout parameter. Are you saying there is a way to do an end run around tSQLt and set the parameter that will override whatever values tSQLt uses when it runs?

Comment: Just one thought on this, have you tried running tSQLt from the command line (using sqlcmd or sql-ps)?  Or if this is just a one off, you could even run it in SSMS and just export the results window as "evidence". I don't think I've ever seen a tSQLt timeout in SSMS and we regularly used to run >6000 tests in around 18 minutes without issue.  Although, when running those tests in VSTS we had to run class by class to avoid timeouts in our CI process. The timeout may be within SQL Test rather than the tSQLt framework itself.

Comment: Thank you @datacentricity! It turns out you were right to be skeptical. Upon further testing it appears that my issue is with Redgate SQL Test, not tSQLt. I ran one of my tests using tSQLt.Run as you suggested. I should be careful what I wish for, as it is still running 19 hours later. To verify that it is not just stuck I created a fake stored procedure that only performs a WAITFOR DELAY '00:10' and created a unit test for this procedure. The unit test run through SQL Test times out. The unit test using tSQLt.Run succeeds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The timeout issue turned out to be within Redgate SQL Test. Therefore, the simple solution for long running unit tests would be to run them directly in the tSQLt framework by calling tSQLt.Run. In my testing, tSQLt does not appear to have a timeout issue. As of this writing, I have a unit test that has been running continuously for 19 hours without timing out.

This unit test, taking so long to run, creates it's own problem in my particular case. I will solve this issue with a hashing solution or EXCEPT solution as discussed in the thread on the response from @datacentricity.

Answer (score 1):

tSQLt probably wouldn't be my first choice for this kind of testing, it is designed for and totally rocks at unit testing - small, usually fast tests of small parts of code.  You could look at something like [DbFit](http://dbfit.github.io/dbfit/) but that will also struggle with that volume of data.

If you really must demonstrate that every column of every row on every table is identical I would look at creating an MD5 hash column on each table in both databases then just query each table for rows where the hash doesn't match.  When building the hash value you will need to exclude any columns that you cannot guarantee would be the same in both tables e.g. IDENTITY values, load date/times etc.  For example:

`--! Create our existing table structures
create table dbo.ExistingCustomer
(
  CustomerId int not null identity(1,1) primary key
, LastName varchar(50) not null
, FirstName varchar(50) not null
, MiddleName varchar(50) null
, TownOfBirth varchar(50) null
, DateOfBirth datetime not null
, NumberOfDependents int not null
, EtlCreatedOn datetime not null
)
go`

--! Add a computed column that concatenates all columns of interest
--! into a single string, handling NULL's in the process, then creates
--! 32 characater MD5 hash over the whole string
alter table dbo.ExistingCustomer
add DeltaHash as
    convert(nvarchar(32), hashbytes('MD4'
        , convert(nvarchar(max)
            --! Even though you might reasonably expect first and last names ot be populated,
            --! always code defensively has hashing over a series of empty strings will give
            --! less confident results
            , coalesce(nullif(LastName, ''), 'LastName')
            + coalesce(nullif(FirstName, ''), 'FirstName')
            --! This pattern is also effective for nullable columns
            + coalesce(nullif(MiddleName, ''), 'MiddleName')
            + coalesce(convert(char(24), TownOfBirth, 121), 'TownOfBirth')
            + coalesce(cast(NumberOfDependents as varchar(32)), 'NumberOfDependents')) collate Latin1_General_CI_AS), 2) persisted
go

When building this hash, you will need to be really wary of collation (between the two databases or even at column level) and spaces.  Imagine you have four integer columns in a row all of which are NULL bar one column.  If you replace null with just an empty string, the MD5 hash will be the same whether the second or third column contains a valid integer.

You would need to add this column to both the old table and the copy of the newly loaded data, then you could use a query like this:

`--! Expect Zero
select
    count(*) as [FailCount]
from
    OldLoadDb.dbo.ExistingCustomer as ec
inner join NewLoadDb.dbo.NewCustomer as nc
    --! This join should probably be on some business key but you get the idea
    on nc.CustomerId = ec.CustomerId
where
    ec.DeltaHash <> ec.DeltaHash
go`

Something like the above would run quite nicely in DbFit as all the grunt work is being done server side.

You should also add tests for row that exist in one table and not in the other.

Of course the hash query won't tell you what the differences are but will at least allow you to identify the rows that are different.

Comment: I am not familiar with DbFit. What about it would make it more suited to this sort of testing? Is it more robust than tSQLt? Your solution may be what I have to end up going with. Using tSQLt was a nice idea, because I didn't have to track down the primary keys of each table and include code referencing them in each table test. But, if that's what I have to do, then that's what I have to do. If it seems that no one has a better solution to my problem, I will go ahead and mark this as the answer.

Comment: DbFit includes a Test Fixture it calls "stored query" which works quite nicely for comparing the contents of tables in two databases on different servers.  I know you can do the same using Linked Server queries - although not with tSQLt.  The disadvantage with DbFit is that it renders all the rows including pass/fail info, cell by cell as html on a wiki page. So whilst not so good for large data volumes, it does give a nice visual representation of all the passes and failures.  I have had great success using DbFit as an ETL integration testing framework on smaller (test/sample) data sets

Comment: One final thought on the MD5 hash approach - if your tables are well structured - i.e. the ETL audit columns you want to exclude renamed the same on all tables and there is some kind of programmatically understandable pattern to the primary/unique keys you want to use, it should be too difficult to auto-generate the above ALTER TABLE and comparison queries from metadata (INFORMATION_SCHEMA views etc).  It will depend on how many tables you need to do this for I guess.  Sadly, explaining how to do this would be a whole blog post in it's own right :-)

Comment: I'd stay away from a short hash like MD5 for this. SQL Server has the ability to calculate "cryptographically secure" hashes that would be more appropriate for this type of problem. However, you can easily get away without a hash by using SQL Server's built-in `EXCEPT` statement - at least if your tables have a primary key. Without a primary key, you'd have to use write something like the table compare algorithm that tSQLt is using. tSQLt basically is counting all equal rows in each table using `GROUP BY` on all columns and then compare the count together with all other columns.

Comment: Keep in mind that you'd have to do `SELECT * FROM A.dbo.table EXCEPT SELECT * FROM B.dbo.table` as well as `SELECT * FROM B.dbo.table EXCEPT SELECT * FROM A.dbo.table` to catch both missing and additional rows.